# How can I do memory profiling and debugging on my macos m2 max with clang/llvm on bazel?

Tags: macos, clang, c++20, bazel

I can't use Valgrind and gperftools tools because of the macOS arm architecture. Unfortunately I can't find errors due to segment and memory leaks because I can't debug and memory profiling. I also need to analyse memory usage.

Language,Tools and technologies I use
c++20(>=)
Bazel
Clang/llvm (https://github.com/grailbio/bazel-toolchain)
VsCode

The technology I developed is a matrix database system with my own algorithm. The project is very branched and difficult to develop. I need to learn as much as possible about execution-related data usage and identify performance problems early. I would like help from people who are experienced in this field.

I tried to use Valgrind and gperftools, but I could not make any progress due to incompatibilities with macos arm. I decided to use LLVM xray, but the https://github.com/grailbio/bazel-toolchain tool I use does not give access to xray.

Briefly what I want is
To gain the pprof feature like in Golang and to be able to visualise this output when needed.

Comment: address sanitizer?

Comment: I get the error "dyld[65858]: symbol not found in flat namespace '___asan_option_detect_stack_use_after_return'"

Comment: I also need a gprof-like output